# LibStatusBar icon disappears on 3rd-party app launch

Tags: ios, ios7, jailbreak, cydia, libstatusbar

I wrote a tweak for Cydia, it adds an icon to the status bar.
It works fine on the home screen and when SpringBoard is launched, also, if an app is already launched then it works fine,
however, if an app (such as Facebook or Twitter) is closed (completely) and the icon is showing, when launching the app, it will cause the icon to disappear.
The icon is displayed using libStatusBar using this code:

```
if(icon) // if icon needs to be removed
{
    [icon release];
    icon = nil;
}

...

// add the icon to the status bar
icon = [[%c(LSStatusBarItem) alloc] initWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"muteIconLablabla"] alignment:StatusBarAlignmentRight];
icon.imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mute"];
```

I also tried using the methods suggested in `libStatusBar` README file

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] addStatusBarImageNamed:@"ON_Mute"]; // and removeStatusBarImageNamed:...
```

I tried overriding `-(id)init` and updating the icon there, but the same result.

The code shown above is being called from a `static void` function. this function is being called several times, for example from `-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application`
 under `%hook SpringBoard` and `-(void)ringerChanged:(int)changed`

All inside `Tweak.xm`.
The problem happens in `iOS7` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used libstatusbar, but if you are absolutely sure the `LSStatusBarItem` is not being released, it's possible it's being hidden by Springboard or another app.  Consider setting `icon.visible = YES` explicitly.  You also might want to consider setting `timeHidden` on `LSStatusBarServer` to `NO` explicitly by calling `[item setHidesTime:NO]`.

Additionally, if you're not making any changes to the icon, set `icon.manualUpdate = NO`.

References:

- [Libstatusbar on the iPhoneDevWiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Libstatusbar)
- [LSStatusBarItem.mm source](https://github.com/phoenix3200/libstatusbar/blob/master/LSStatusBarItem.mm)